# How to get the particular value from the GROUP_CONTACT column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying in MYSQL, please suggest the expected result

Thank you in advance

table 1

| year | Cars |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | BMW |
| 2000 | Maruti Suzuki |
| 2000 | TOYOTA |
| 2001 | Volkswagen |
| 2001 | Daimler |
| 2001 | Chevrolet |

OUTPUT

| Year | Cars |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | BMW, Maruti Suzuki, TOYOTA |
| 2001 | Volkswagen, Daimler, Chevrolet |

EXPECTING THE BELOW OUTPUT

| Year | Car Model | TOYOTA | FORD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | BMW, Maruti Suzuki, TOYOTA | YES | NO |
| 2001 | Volkswagen, Daimler, Chevrolet | NO | NO |

I used following query

```
SELECT 

GROUP_CONCAT (distinct table1.year, table1.Cars ASC Separator ',') as Car Model

FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with this query even without GROUP_CONCAT (case table1.Cars

when 'TOYOTA' then 'YES' END 'NO')  I suggest you fix before attempting this.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how should I get the particular value from the "Car model" column

Comment: There is, currently, no `Car model` column, because your query has problems, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/l_xd6xPi.   Also why do you want/need to group_concat the data from Table1, and then find a certain value in that? That value should exists in Table1, and can be found easy using standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   year INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Cars VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(year,Cars) VALUES 
(2000,'BMW'),
(2000,'Maruti Suzuki'),
(2000,'TOYOTA'),
(2001,'Volkswagen'),
(2001,'Daimler'),
(2001,'Chevrolet');
```

use `IF` and `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
select year,
GROUP_CONCAT(Cars) as Cars,
IF(GROUP_CONCAT(Cars) LIKE '%TOYOTA%','YES','NO')  TOYOTA,
IF(GROUP_CONCAT(Cars) LIKE '%FORD%','YES','NO')  FORD
  from mytable
group by year
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hxIk9j0N)

Comment: `.. IF(MAX(Cars = 'TOYOTA'), 'YES', 'NO') ..`

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way of doing it.

```
SELECT
    tmp.*,
    IF(
        LOCATE('TOYOTA',tmp.car_model,1),
        'YES',
        'NO'
    ) AS 'TOYOTA',
    IF(
        LOCATE('Ford',tmp.car_model,1),
        'YES',
        'NO'
    ) AS 'Ford'
FROM (
    SELECT
        year,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT car ORDER BY car ASC) AS car_model
    FROM cars
    GROUP BY year
) tmp
ORDER BY year ASC
```

What you see here is a sub-query in action.

First, the part within `FROM ( .... ) tmp` creates a temporary table with two columns - `year` and `car_model`. The column `car_model` is a concatenated string with unique models.

Next, we query **that** temporary table, by using it as a source for our new query, which checks up whether `TOYOTA` and `Ford` are present in any of its rows.

However, if you need to check for every single car model, and having a separate `IF` column for each and every one of them, you would probably be better off dynamically creating your query with something like PHP, or any other server-side language which works with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Simply combine a *group_concat* aggregate with standard conditional aggregation:

```
select Year, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct cars order by cars asc) CarModel,
    max(case when cars = 'TOYOTA' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) TOYOTA,
    max(case when cars = 'FORD' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) FORD
from t
group by year;
```